# How to prevent tramp data while implementing caller-specific singletons in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I wrote a class library for logging and diagnostics. The interface is pretty basic. You call these static methods to log something:

```
interface ILogger {
  void Critical (string message);
  void Error (string message);
  void Warning (string message);
  void Info (string message);
  void Verbose (string message);
}
```

However, I want to append a call context (let's say trace identifier) **implicitly** to the each message and I want that context to be set/reset by callers of the library (specifically top level caller) rather than pushing trace context down to each method call. Assuming that **context can be updated at runtime**, the updated information needs to retraverse all the layers. In fact, the trace context can be extended in the future too. So having context passed around each and every method/constructor initialization is definitely not a good design choice.

Given the fact that library is used in different layers of the code and called by various classes and these callers may fork other multiple threads, I want to be able to implement **caller-specific singletons - global data that's only global to that caller**.

Let's say the top level class can only set/reset the identifier via some `Register (Guid traceId)` method and down-the-path the callers just call log methods and do not care about the **context**. Be aware that the number of layers could be high. Think about the following and consider when the number of layers is tens and maybe hundreds making it really really hard to pass the context and make sure log method calls are aware of any update:

```
class A {
  private B bObj;

  void Do() {
    bObj.DoSomethingElse();
    Logger.Critical("some message from A");
  }
}

class B {
  private C cObj;

  void DoSomethingElse() {
    cObj.DoAnotherThing();
    Logger.Critical("some message from B");
  }
}

class C {
  private D dObj;

  void DoAnotherThing() {
    dObj.DoSomethingElse();
    Logger.Critical("some message from C");
  }
}
```

I did a quick research find out [ThreadStatic, CallContext and HttpContext in ASP.Net](http://piers7.blogspot.com/2005/11/threadstatic-callcontext-and_02.html), but I couldn't wrap my head around this without having `System.Web` in multithread environment. `ThreadStatic` could be the solution, but my main source of confusion is that a caller may fork new threads and what happens to that existing context from that point on in child threads.

In summary, I am looking for a solution that does not require traversing tramp data to callers of the library (method calls or constructors doesn't matter), and I want to keep log method calls to be aware of any updates to the context data.

NOTE: I am not really sure if **caller-specific singletons** is right way to put this.

UPDATE: Jon Skeet has [an article](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/11/08/the-importance-of-context-and-a-question-of-explicitness/) on this issue.

Comment: what about using an `IDisposable`? You then could  use a `using` block and can scope to that. Or each caller could call `EnterContext` and `LeaveContext` as needed if it doesn't want to put the context to any other calls.

Comment: You still need to pass that context information down to callers so that they can enter that context and leave it. Tramp data issue is still there. Plus, any update to the context would require more data travel top to bottom. I want to have that context globally stored and updated without affecting callers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found out Stephen Cleary's article [Implicit Async Context ("AsyncLocal")](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html). He provides example of how to maintain an implicit context that can flow into the threads.

In my case, the following solves the tramp data traversal:

```
interface ILogger {
  void Critical (string message);
  void Error (string message);
  void Warning (string message);
  void Info (string message);
  void Verbose (string message);

  void SetContext(string context);
  string GetContext();
}

class Logger : ILogger {
  void Critical(string message) {
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", GetContext(), message));
  }

  void SetContext(string context) {
    CallContext.LogicalSetData("myContext", context);
  }

  string GetContext() {
    return (string)CallContext.LogicalGetData("myContext") ?? string.Empty;
  }
}
```

Each log method call retrieves the implicit context using `CallContext`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing pure data results for example `List<Customer>` between layers you can create a `MessageEnvelope<List<Customer>>` class. In this MessageEnvelope class you can then have a property of `IContext` and also a GUID identifier and additional data that you need for your application.
So you have to refactor your code then of course.

This would also work in N-Tier scenarios.
I would not use singetons!

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, I always prefer to think in terms of **decoration**. Specifically, you have your interface

```
interface ILogger {
  void Critical (string message);
}
```

then you have a concrete logger

```
public class ConcreteLogger : ILogger {
  public void Cricital( string message ) {
     // log somewhere
  }
}
```

and then you have your decorators that can be composed

```
public class ContextAwareLogger : ILogger {

   private string context;
   private ILogger decorated;      

   public ContextAwareLogger( string context, ILogger decorated ) {
      this.context = context;
      this.decorated = decorated;
   }

   public void Critical( string message ) {
      this.decorated.Critical( this.context + this.message );
   }
}
```

and last but not least, you have a factory:

```
public class LoggerFactory {

   public ILogger Create( string context ) {

      if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( context ) )
         return new ContextAwareLogger( context, new ConcreteLogger() );
      else
         return new ConcreteLogger();

   }
}
```

This gives your client a detailed control over what happens, without really changing their interface:

```
// client code

// no context
var logger = new LoggerFactory().Create( null );
logger.Critical( "a critical issue" );

// with context
var logger2 = new LoggerFactory().Create( "context" );
logger2.Critical( "a critical issue" );
```

Hope you get the idea. Having a bunch of different decorators and a smart factory with several different ways to parametrize your logger creation, you can still rely on the very same logger interface and you let the additional work be done by specific decorators.

Comment: This solution requires the tramp data (context) to travel all the way down to maybe not method calls, but to the constructors at least. And this needs a way to reinitialize the loggers if context changes.

Comment: You always use the factory to create a fresh instance.